# Can't find variable Symbol using React Native with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using the ES6 `Symbol` in my React Native project. This works fine for iOS, but on Android I get `Can't find variable: Symbol`.

I'm using TypeScript, and I've tried various `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es7"],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
}
```

I've also tried `lib: ["dom", "es6"]` and `["dom", "es6", "es7"]` as well as `target: "es5"`.

How can I get `Symbol` to be properly handled by TypeScript for React Native on Android?

Comment: I think your error is not related to Typescript or transpiling, it's more a native android java issue.

Comment: I think there should be a way to get TypeScript to transpile `Symbol` based on the target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `import 'core-js/es6/symbol'` without having to add an npm dependency or copy pasting an polyfill

EDIT: I doubt that it is a TS problem. Android JS runtime doesn't have Symbol support. I had this problem in plain JSX too and fixed it using the snippet pasted above.

Comment: Yes. But it comes with ReactNative or as its dependency maybe. Didn't have to add another dependency myself.

Comment: Ah I see. I was going for a general solution. Anyway, your remarks are correct about it not being TS related.

Answer (score 0):

This a TypeScript issue at all.

You are missing a polyfill.

As a transpiler, TypeScript transforms syntactic constructs so as to represent their behavior but it does not provide runtime libraries.

Install [an es6-symbol polyfill like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-symbol) with your package manager of choice and everything will be well.

Symbol is a library, and outside the scope of transpilation in general, at least from the TypeScript team's perspective.

Part of the motivation for this is that you can choose your own polyfill implementations, giving you flexibility. Another that comes to mind is that a transpiler is often invoked well before it would have sufficient information to know if it could exclude a polyfill.

**Note:** Your `--target` is set to `es2015` but you are experiencing difficulties on some platforms due to libraries that were specified in `es2015` not being provided by the runtime. I strongly advise that you lower use `--target es5` for the time being.

One more thing I suggest is being consistent in your config terminology.

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": ["dom", "es7"],
```

is confusing and should be changed to

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": ["dom", "es2016"],
```

for the sake of the reader

Answer (score 0):

You can import these in your root `index.js` file without installing any dependencies:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```