# How to solve can't find variable: Symbol in react native even with upgrade jsc-android

Tags: android, react-native

I have my react native app working on iOS, but it fails on Android with the error `Can't find variable: Symbol in react native`.

I followed ([Can't find variable Symbol using React Native with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931866/cant-find-variable-symbol-using-react-native-with-typescript)), but that didn't work.

So instead I upgraded the jsc-android libraries to `"jsc-android": "^236355.1.1",`, and fixed up my gradle files per (https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#how-to-use-it-with-my-react-native-app), but I'm still getting the same error. It seems like everything should be on the latest js engine which is supposed to support es2016, but so far I haven't had any luck in getting it to work on android. Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.1",
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "fetch-intercept": "^2.3.1",
    "https-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "jsc-android": "^236355.1.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-os": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-plotly": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-voice": "^0.2.6",
    "react-navigation": "^3.1.5",
    "readable-stream": "^1.1.14",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "ts-optchain": "^0.1.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.14",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.21",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.34",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "rn-nodeify": "github:tradle/rn-nodeify",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "tslint-react-recommended": "^1.0.15",
    "typescript": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  }
}
```

My /android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

and my /android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myappid"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r236355'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-udp')
    implementation project(':react-native-tcp')
    implementation project(':react-native-os')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-randombytes')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-voice')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```